# Rails memcache store default auto expiration time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I have been struggling for a while to find out if there is some default expiration time set by Rails, in case we don't provide any while storing a key-value pair to memcache?
e.g. Rails.cache.write('some-key', 'some-value')

Would rails set some expiration time by default if we haven't specified?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the default, built-in `MemCacheStore` class provided by Rails, then no. It won't assume an expiry time when you create new cache entries. You can [read the applicable code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/mem_cache_store.rb#L132) to verify that. It checks to see if you've passed an `expires_in` option to the `#write` method like

```
Rails.cache.write("key", "content", expires_in: 2.hours)
```

and if you haven't, simply passes 0 to memcache indicating no expiry time. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the newer (and I think better) [Dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) memcached gem, you can configure it at the adapter-level using a line like the following:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'cache-1.example.com', 'cache-2.example.com',
  { :namespace => NAME_OF_RAILS_APP, :expires_in => 1.day}
```

See the [README](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) for a detailed explanation of the `:expires_in` option. Overall, I think Dalli is worth checking out for more than just this feature, its also faster and supports some newer authentication features, etc.

Comment: Good call. `MemCacheStore` is just a thin wrapper over Dalli, after all.